# How to use sed, perl to rename files and its contents with a particular pattern in a given directory?

Tags: linux, perl, find, sed

Given a directory "Centos1" which has few files named Centos1.x, Centos1.y, Centos1.z and these files also has "Centos1" in their contents. Using a single command ( using find, sed, perl -pie ) how can I get them renamed to "Centos2" for all occurence of "Centos1"
Here are the content of Centos1 directory.

```
Centos1.nvram      Centos1-s005.vmdk  Centos1.vmsd  vmware-2.log
Centos1-s001.vmdk  Centos1-s006.vmdk  Centos1.vmx   vmware.log
Centos1-s002.vmdk  Centos1-s007.vmdk  Centos1.vmxf
Centos1-s003.vmdk  Centos1-s008.vmdk  vmware-0.log
Centos1-s004.vmdk  Centos1.vmdk       vmware-1.log
```

NOTE: I want to have "Centos1" replaced with "Centos2" inside all files too if it's present.

I ran the below mentioned command after I changed to "Centos1" directory

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/Centos1/Centos2/g' {} +
```

But it didn't help. Any input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the rename command to do the renaming

```
rename Centos1 Centos2 *
```

or if you have the perl rename

```
rename 's/Centos1/Centos2' *
```

Your find command should change all occurences of Centos1 to Centos2 so you could wrap them in a simple script to make it a single command.

```
#!/bin/bash
rename Centos1 Centos2 *

find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/Centos1/Centos2/g' {} +
```

Comment: But has is this "rename" command the perl one or util-linux package one ?

Comment: @AshutoshNarayan: On the CentOS system I tested on it's a binary. I just checked an Ubuntu system which has the perl script. I've updated my answer to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Does your answer really need to include only these commands, or can you use bash builtins and file globbing?

```
for file in Centos1*; do
  sed -i 's/Centos1/Centos2/g' "$file"
  mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed 's/^Centos1/Centos2/')"
done
```

**Edit:** Using just find/sed, and renames inside files

```
find ./ -type f -name Centos1* -exec sh -c 'sed -i "s/Centos1/Centos2/g" "$1"; mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed "s/Centos1/Centos2/")"' X '{}' \;
```